# Anyone have a custom webview implementation with flash i can use?

Tags: javascript, java, android, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I know later versions of android webview don't have this ability. However, I know the pidgeon browser has its own implementation that allows flash to run.

I have been searching for a while and have not found much, but, does anyone know of a good AS3 and AS2 interpreter in javascript or a custom webview implementation that I can include in my app?

I was using phonegap, but I can do it in android studio if I could just find a good webview implementation with flash..

BTW working with the clubpenguinrewritten team to get a mobile app working while we rewrite the client.

EDIT: i tried with interpreting with swf2js.js but sadly it's as3 support is a little sad...

Comment: not sure if it will help - but [haxe](https://haxe.org/) may be the solution

Comment: I'll look into it a bit more before i say anything definative but converting it sounds very painful with how the club penguin client is setup.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure as I said. It just popped in my head because it's pretty much AS3 - you could use it to translate your flash code, rather than finding some way to run flash :p

Comment: Yeah that sadly may be where I end up though so thanks for the suggestion XD
Preparing for the conversion mentally..